# Make Inline Div Animate To Fixed Bottom Right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have all the code working except for getting it to animate. I want a div container to be inline on the page and once that div hits the top of the page on scroll, I want that div to be stuck to the bottom right of the page.

I have all of the above working, but the part I can't get is to make that transition animate so it's not a quick shift from inline to bottom right.

Here is my working code so far. The part I can't get to work is to use the .animate function as i'm swapping classes.

```js
var $window   = $( window );
var $container   = $( '#container' );
var containerTop  = $container.offset().top;

$window.scroll( function() {
 if( $window.scrollTop() > containerTop ) {
  pullContainer();
 } else {
  revertContainer();
 }
});

function pullContainer ( ) {
 $container.removeClass( 'inline' ).addClass( 'fixed' );
}

function revertContainer ( ) {
 $container.removeClass( 'fixed' ).addClass( 'inline' );
}
```

```css
#header {
 background: #666;
 height: 75vh;
}

#content{
 background: #eee;
 height: 75vh;
}

#footer {
 background: #ccc;
 height: 75vh;
}

#container{
 background: red;
 width: 50%;
}
.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.inline {
 position: static;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="container">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

edit: this code doesn't seem to work correctly within the stackoverflow snippet viewer, but it works just fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `bottom:100%;right:100%` on `.inline`

You cannot transition on `position`.

https://jsfiddle.net/k27rkxfe/

css:

```
#header {
    background: #666;
    height: 75vh;
}

#content{
    background: #eee;
    height: 75vh;
}

#footer {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 75vh;
}

#container{
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
  transition:all 0.3s;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.inline {
    position: inline;
  bottom:100%;
  right:100%;

}
```

javascript:

```
var $window         = $( window );
var $container      = $( '#container' );
var containerTop    = $container.offset().top;

$window.scroll( function() {
console.log($window.scrollTop(), containerTop)
    if( $window.scrollTop() > containerTop ) {
        pullContainer();
    } else {
        revertContainer();
    }
});

function pullContainer ( ) {
    if ($container.hasClass('fixed'))return;
    $container.toggleClass('fixed inline');
}

function revertContainer ( ) {
    if ($container.hasClass('inline'))return;
    $container.toggleClass('fixed inline');
}
```